# Using e-mail on malware infected computer/network

Tags: ssl, smtp, imap, malware, pop3

I have an important (+10 outlook accounts) but very ignorant client who refuses to accept that there is malware on the company's computers. Malware that steals Outlook data to send and receive spam. The situation went on a limit, due to the stubbornness of the client and with that I decided to raise the anti-spam filter. That started to make the customer more satisfied because he no longer receives return messages associated with the malware (lots of Chinese messages). It is not a sustainable situation because normal messages are being filtered.

Any suggestions (without being rid of the client), please?

PS: I'm not the network administrator of this company (who thinks just like the customer!) just the website and email service provider.

Comment: How do you know that malware is responsible for this? What proof do you have? What proof can you show the customer?

Comment: This is too broad ("how do I fix malware?") and since any solutions are not yours to implement, it's not really answerable.

Comment: @joeqwerty
1st: I changed the passwords. The problem continued.
2nd: I found there were returned e-mails (from qq.com) with headers containing information of the client's network IP and computers names.
3rd: to reinforce that the origin of the problem was in their computers I did remote access using TeamViewer and I ran MalwareBytes witch reported lot of malware related with spambots. 
4th: I reported to client their tech support company and they insisted the problem is my e-mail server. Then I just raised the server antispam limits to a bigger value. Making the client ignorantly happier.

Answer (score 1):

Leave him be, you have no control. He will soon enough be listed in RBL, after that no email would be accepted from remote server when your client will email, your client might change his view then

You can ask their admin if they have SPF record, has the response back can be an answer, but not from a email sent by them if SPF record are not set.